# Questions over BigInteger?

Tags: java, biginteger

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class ProjectEuler {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger("600851475143");
        int div = 7;
        while (bi.compareTo(new BigInteger("1")) != 0) {
            while (bi.mod(new BigInteger(div + "")).compareTo(new BigInteger("0")) == 0) {
                bi = bi.divide(new BigInteger(div + ""));
            }
            div += 2;
        }
        System.out.println("" + div);
    }
}
```

I was just looking over one of the basic but famous problems of "**What is the largest prime factor of the number 600851475143**". I found this solution different, i have a couple of questions on how this works.

1. The first condition checks whether the number equals 1 or not. From there i am not able to understand the rest of the code.
2. `new BigInteger(div +"")`. why do we concatenate + "" here?

Comment: Probably the author noticed that the number isn't divisible by 2 nor 3 nor 5. It's no rocket science.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: 2 Negatives in couple of seconds...

Comment: "From there i am not able to understand the rest of the code." - have you tried consulting the [`BigInteger` javadocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)? If so, is there anything *specific* you don't understand?

Comment: Searching for ["add empty string java"](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+add+empty+string) gives me [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626917/add-an-empty-string-vs-tostring-why-is-it-bad) [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506474/is-concatenating-with-an-empty-string-to-do-a-string-conversion-really-that-bad) SO questions and a whole bunch of other results that could shine light on that issue.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza That raises a silly question: would that make the fastest answer to this Project Euler problem hardcoding the result you calculate beforehand?

Comment: @millimoose no indeed, it won't be faster. Just to note, I solved that problem using `long` values only, no need of `BigInteger`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: the question might look silly for many, but i usually tell many that the "for OP it does not". Let's teach and pass wisdom....

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Haven't played around with PE much, but the solution above misses more low hanging fruit than that...

Comment: @Vinothbabu You're mashing several comments together. The "silly" question was one I raised. The OP's question is merely low quality - very vague, shows zero own research, etc.

Comment: @millimoose: chill guys.. no offense to anyone here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How is the div = 7 decided?

The author decided to "hard-code" his knowledge of the number itself to decide that the first three primes are not among the divisors

> The first condition checks whether the number equals 1 or not. From there i am not able to understand the rest of the code.

The rest of the code looks like this in "regular" integers:

```
while (bi % div == 0) {
    bi /= div;
}
div += 2;
```

> `new BigInteger(div +"")` why do we concatenate `+ ""` here

That is a short way of making an object a `String`.  `BigInteger` has a parameter that takes `String`, so the alternative to this approach would be calling `Integer.toString(div)`.

Note that this is not the most efficient solution: one could speed this up by observing that you could stop trying to divide when you reach the square root of the original number, because you can be sure that the next divisor will be the number itself.

Comment: @excellent, can you just explain the last paragraph little more, "one could speed this up by observing that you could stop trying to divide when you reach the square root of the original number, because you can be sure that the next divisor will be the number itself."

Comment: @Kevin this is better explained here: [Prime Factorization Calculator](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/prime-number/prime-factorization-calculator.php)

Answer (score 1):

> How is the div = 7 decided?

Probably the author noticed that the number isn't divisible by 2 nor 3 nor 5. To know how the author did this, he/she should have known this rules: [Divisibility Rules and Tests](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/arithmetic/numbers/divisibility-rules-and-tests.php)

> The first condition checks whether the number equals 1 or not. From there i am not able to understand the rest of the code.

The author is making sure that the number is not `BigInteger("1")`  since it's dividing the number and storing the results in `bi` in the loop iterations. Note this:

```
bi = bi.divide(new BigInteger(div + ""));
```

> `new BigInteger(div +"")`. why do we concatenate + "" here?

It uses the [`BigInteger(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#BigInteger%28java.lang.String%29) constructor. The author n̶a̶i̶v̶e̶l̶y̶  makes a new `String` by adding the `int` with an empty `String`.