# Java: Is the method Integer.toString() better than adding empty string to integer type value?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is conversion to String using (“” + <int value>) bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572708/is-conversion-to-string-using-int-value-bad-practice)

I am testing some Java codes with PMD rules. One of the rules for efficiency is a 'AddingEmptyString'. Below is a description for the rule.

> Finds empty string literals which are being added. This is an inefficient way to convert any type to a String.

```
    String s = "" + 123; // bad 
    String t = Integer.toString(456); // ok
```

Could you explain why Integer.toString is better than adding empty string to integer type value?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572708/is-conversion-to-string-using-int-value-bad-practice and  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2506474/is-concatenating-with-an-empty-string-to-do-a-string-conversion-really-that-bad

Comment: I use the former well, always, over the latter. Premature optimization is the r... anyway. Who says `"" + 123` is bad? :p Unless there is a *specific* "too slow" performance case tested (and verified), I'd argue *for* the former.

Comment: I also use the former.  However correct, the latter is a good example if Java's gawkiness.

Comment: Given that StringBuilder.append(int) eventually calls Integer.toString(int) what do you think ?

Answer (score 6):

It's bad because the first way does more operations than the second. The compiler will translate the first line into the equivalent of

```
String s = "" + Integer.toString(123);
```

Which has an extra string concatenation when compared to

```
String t = Integer.toString(456);
```

Even if the compiler optimizes away the concatenation with the empty string, the purpose of the line of code is much more clear when Integer.toString is used explicitly.

Comment: Actually "" + 123 ends up being a new StringBuilder().append("").append(123).toString().

Answer (score -1):

in the first example you're instantiating a String object ("") and then another String object to hold the result of Integer to String conversion, 2 objects created in all;

The second you're only creating one string object, which is created when you do the Integer.toString()

Comment: Who cares if a new/intermediate string object is used and/or created?

Comment: the poster cares, as he asked about the difference in terms of efficiency.

Answer (score -1):

It's also bad because String concatenation is a relatively expensive operation.  Using StringBuilder would likely be slightly more efficient than your first fragment.  You might note that you will commonly see something like System.out.println(""+i) where i is an int but this concatenation is quite unnecessary, not to say wrong.  This is the equivalent of ...println(""+Integer.valueOf(i).toString()) which looks a lot more messy but does the same thing.  ...println(i) works just fine.

Comment: Relatively expensive -- to what? (And who cares?)