# String valueOf vs concatenation with empty string

Tags: java

I am working in Java code optimization. I'm unclear about the difference between `String.valueOf` or the `+""` sign:

```
int intVar = 1;
String strVar = intVar + "";
String strVar = String.valueOf(intVar);
```

What is the difference between line 2 and 3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is conversion to String using ("" + <int value>) bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1572708/is-conversion-to-string-using-int-value-bad-practice)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

```
public void foo(){
int intVar = 5;
String strVar = intVar+"";    
}
```

This approach uses StringBuilder to create resultant String

```
public void foo();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_5
   1:   istore_1
   2:   new     #2; //class java/lang/StringBuilder
   5:   dup
   6:   invokespecial   #3; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
   9:   iload_1
   10:  invokevirtual   #4; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lan
g/StringBuilder;
   13:  ldc     #5; //String
   15:  invokevirtual   #6; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/
String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
   18:  invokevirtual   #7; //Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/la
ng/String;
   21:  astore_2
   22:  return
```

---

```
public void bar(){
int intVar = 5;
String strVar = String.valueOf(intVar);
}
```

This approach invokes simply a static method of `String` to get the String version of int

```
public void bar();
  Code:
   0:   iconst_5
   1:   istore_1
   2:   iload_1
   3:   invokestatic    #8; //Method java/lang/String.valueOf:(I)Ljava/lang/Stri
ng;
   6:   astore_2
   7:   return
```

which in turn calls [`Integer.toString()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Integer.java#Integer.toString%28int%2Cint%29)

Comment: What this doesn't tell us is whether the JIT compiler will optimize (particularly) the first version to a simpler form.

Comment: So which one is better?

Answer (score 29):

Ask yourself the purpose of the code. Is it to:

- Concatenate an empty string with a value
- Convert a value to a string

It sounds much more like the latter to me... which is why I'd use `String.valueOf`. Whenever you can make your code read in the same way as you'd describe what you want to achieve, that's a good thing.

Note that this works for all types, and will return "null" when passed a null reference rather than throwing a `NullPointerException`. If you're using a class (not an `int` as in this example) and you *want* it to throw an exception if it's null (e.g. because that represents a bug), call `toString` on the reference instead.

Comment: `String.valueOf(int x)` *invokes simply a static method of String to get the String version of int*. When we talk about Android, it is recommended to *avoid* using static methods. What do you think about this approach in Android?

Answer (score 11):

I'd prefer `valueOf()`, because I think it's more readable and explicit.

Any concerns about performance are micro-optimizations that wouldn't be measurable.  I wouldn't worry about them until I could take a measurement and see that they made a difference.

Answer (score 10):

Using `String.valueOf(int)`, or better, `Integer.toString(int)` is relatively more efficient for the machine.  However, unless performance is critical (in which case I wouldn't suggest you use either) Then `""+ x` is much more efficient use of your time.  IMHO, this is usually more important.  Sometimes massively more important.

In other words, `""+` wastes an object, but `Integer.toString()` creates several anyway.  Either your time is more important or you want to avoid creating objects at all costs.  You are highly unlikely to be in the position that creating several objects is fine, but creating one more is not.

Comment: Nice phrase: "Then ""+ x is much more efficient use of your time. IMHO, this is usually more important. "

Answer (score 8):

Well, if you look into the JRE source code, `Integer.getChars(...)` is the most vital method which actually does the conversion from integer to char[], but it's a package-private method.
So the question is how to get this method called with minimum overhead.
Following is an overview of the 3 approaches by tracing the calls to our target method, please look into the JRE source code to understand this better.

1. `"" + intVar` compiles to :
   `new StringBuilder()` => `StringBuilder.append(int)` => `Integer.getChars(...)`
2. `String.valueOf(intVar)` => `Integer.toString(intVar)` => `Integer.getChars(...)`
3. `Integer.toString(intVar)` => `Integer.getChars(...)`

The first method unnecessarily creates one extra object i.e. the StringBuilder.
The second simply delegates to third method.
So you have the answer now.

*PS: Various compile time and runtime optimizations come into play here. So actual performance benchmarks may say something else depending on different JVM implementations which we can't predict, so I generally prefer the approach which looks efficient by looking at the source code.*

Answer (score 5):

The first line is equivalent to

```
String strVal = String.valueOf(intVar) + "";
```

so that there is some extra (and pointless) work to do. Not sure if the compiler optimizes away concatenations with empty string literals. If it does not (and looking at @Jigar's answer it apparently does not), this will in turn become

```
String strVal = new StringBuilder().append(String.valueOf(intVar))
                      .append("").toString();
```

So you should really be using String.valueOf directly.

Answer (score 2):

From the point of optimization , I will always prefer the `String.valueOf()` between the two. The first one is just a hack , trying to trick the conversion of the `intVar` into a `String` because the + operator.

Answer (score 2):

Even though answers here are correct in general, there's one point that is not mentioned.

`"" + intVar` has better performance compared to `String.valueOf()` or `Integer.toString()`. So, if performance is critical, it's better to use empty string concatenation.

See [this talk](https://youtu.be/YgGAUGC9ksk?t=684) by Aleksey Shipilëv. Or [these slides](https://shipilev.net/talks/joker-Oct2014-string-catechism.pdf) of the same talk (slide #24)

Comment: Really interesting! Good to know. Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 1):

Concatenating Strings and other variables actually uses `String.valueOf()` (and `StringBuilder`) underneath, so the compiler will hopefully discard the empty String and produce the same bytecodes in both cases.

Comment: looking at @Jigar's answer it apparently does not do this optimization

Comment: @Thilo: there's more than one Java compiler though.

Answer (score -1):

```
String strVar1 = intVar+"";
String strVar2 = String.valueOf(intVar);
```

strVar1 is equvalent to strVar2, but using int+emptyString "" 
is not elegant way to do it.

using valueOf is more effective.