# difference between String.valueOf(int) , `+` string operator and Integer.toString(int)

Tags: java

Not confident about whether this will be downvoted or closed... I need expert opinion on this.

The context is in our application, we have written code like :

```
//countryId is an integer, searchCity() expects two String parameters
loadCity(countryName , countryId + "");
```

Will it make any difference if I change (I am being forced to do so) the call like :

```
loadCity(countryName, String.valueOf(countryId));
```

Or,

```
loadCity(countryName, Integer.toString(countryId));
```

Will this make any difference in sense of performance?

Comment: It's hard to imagine an application where the method of converting an integer to a string has an effect on performance.

Comment: another thread on SO can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752347/string-valueof-vs-concatenation-with-empty-string

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer.toString(int i) vs String.valueOf(int i)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3335737/integer-tostringint-i-vs-string-valueofint-i)

Comment: from the duplicate question I added, concatenation uses String.valueOf() under the covers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the example you have given, the answer will really depend on the type of 'integer' you are using.

```
loadCity(countryName , countryId + "");
```

For an `Integer` object this is equivelent to :

```
loadCity(countryName, countryId.toString() + "");
```

Whereas for an `int` primitive, this code is equivelent to :

```
loadCity(countryName, String.valueOf(countryId) + "");
```

In either case, as  ArjunShankar pointed out there is a good chance that the compiler has optimised your code anyway. So if your question is 'do I go back and refactor all my code?', then I would say 'don't sweat the small stuff'. But in the future use a more conventional approach to avoid the down votes.

Comment: +1 for saying those two are equivalent. `String` class reference says _String conversions are implemented through the method toString, defined by Object and inherited by all classes in Java._

Comment: When compiling to bytecode, my bet is `+ ""` gets optimized away. So these two should be equivalent to `loadCity (countryName, countryId.toString);`

Comment: thanks for the tip @ArjunShankar . And klonq , you are the only person who understood the scenario. Accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the main difference is *readability*. There's no use in micro-benching here. IMHO `String#valueOf` reads the best.

Answer (score 1):

[From the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf%28char%29) of `String.valueOf`

"The representation is exactly the one returned by the Integer.toString method of one argument."

I would use `String.valueOf` because you can use it on more then just Integers, i.e. you don't have to know whether you have an int, double, bool, etc....

Answer (score 0):

They are  same.... because 
 the method String.valueOf(int i) implicitly calls Integer.toString(i, 10);

Answer (score 0):

A search on both methods informed me all of these are equivalent:

```
    String.valueOf(countryId) 
    Integer.toString(countryId) 
    countryId.toString() //Only if countryId is an Integer
```

Because they all call:

```
    Integer.toString(countryId, 10)
```

The only difference is if you wish to use a different radix, ie:

```
   Integer.toString(countryId, radix)
```

Personally I think `countryId.toString()` reads better when using an Integer. Otherwise `Integer.toString(countryId)` is the way to go. But that is just my personal opinion. Performance-wise you should use `Integer.toString(countryId, 10)`.

I think that adding an empty string to an int to convert it to a String is a bad practice.