# Null pointer on shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I'm implementing shared preferences, and i wanna make appear what was saved before. For this, i'm trying to set the editboxes text, even with the null preferences file. 
I'm not sure if is possible.

```
public class PerfilActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PERFIL_FILE = "MyPreferencesFile";

    private Button btn_historico, btn_actualiza;
    private EditText ed_nome, ed_altura, ed_peso, ed_gordura;
    private SharedPreferences settings;
    private SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);



        btn_actualiza = (Button)findViewById(id.btn_atualizar);
        btn_historico = (Button)findViewById(id.btn_verHistorico);
        ed_nome = (EditText)findViewById(id.ed_nome);
        ed_altura = (EditText)findViewById(id.ed_altura);
        ed_peso = (EditText)findViewById(id.ed_peso);
        ed_gordura = (EditText)findViewById(id.ed_gorduraCorporal);


        ed_nome.setText(settings.getString("nome", "(Insira o nome)"));
        ed_altura.setText(settings.getInt("altura", 1232));
        ed_peso.setText(settings.getInt("peso", 222));
        ed_gordura.setText(settings.getInt("gordura", 123));

        btn_actualiza.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                settings = getSharedPreferences(PERFIL_FILE, 0);
                editor = settings.edit();
                editor.putString("nome", ed_nome.getText().toString());
                editor.putInt("altura", Integer.parseInt(ed_altura.getText().toString()));
                editor.putInt("peso", Integer.parseInt(ed_peso.getText().toString()));
                editor.putInt("gordura", Integer.parseInt(ed_gordura.getText().toString()));
                showToast("Valores actualizados com sucesso!", 1);
                editor.commit();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

LogCat

```
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419): Process: com.AMOV.mr.fit, PID: 31419
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.AMOV.mr.fit/com.AMOV.mr.fit.PerfilActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2212)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2045)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:549)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419): Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:265)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at com.AMOV.mr.fit.PerfilActivity.onCreate(PerfilActivity.java:39)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-03 04:06:24.505: E/AndroidRuntime(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)


01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419): Failed to find resource
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:265)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at com.AMOV.mr.fit.PerfilActivity.onCreate(PerfilActivity.java:39)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2169)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.startActivityNow(ActivityThread.java:2045)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:135)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:347)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:749)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:549)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5146)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
01-03 04:06:24.495: E/ActivityThread(31419):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID Fatal Exception in Main](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191092/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-fatal-except)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x7b

Because you are passing `Integer` to `EditText.setText` method. Use `String.valueOf(<Int value>)` to show value in EditTexts:

```
 ed_altura.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("altura", 1232)));
 ed_peso.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("peso", 222)));
 ed_gordura.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("gordura", 123)));
```

Comment: Thank's! I didn't see that

Answer (score 2):

You *Must Parse* the Value before setting to the `EditText` because value Must be *String Type*

```
ed_altura.setText(settings.getInt("altura", 1232));
        ed_peso.setText(settings.getInt("peso", 222));
        ed_gordura.setText(settings.getInt("gordura", 123));
```

***Replace to***

```
 ed_altura.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("altura", 1232)));
 ed_peso.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("peso", 222)));
 ed_gordura.setText(String.valueOf(settings.getInt("gordura", 123)));
```

Check this it might Help you