# Android 12 - Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-12

**I'm getting the below error on Android 12 devices.**

```
Fatal Exception: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c0025
   at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:240)
   at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1275)
   at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.isTablet(DeviceFormFactor.java:8)
   at cs.a(cs.java:4)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.e(BrowserStartupControllerImpl.java:25)
   at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.g(BrowserStartupControllerImpl.java:26)
   at E8.run(E8.java:127)
   at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.f(ThreadUtils.java:6)
   at EB0.g(EB0.java:209)
   at DB0.run(DB0.java:7)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID Fatal Exception in Main](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191092/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-fatal-except)

Comment: @TomJoney No. This is not the issue.

Comment: That's OK, thanks for the response. Share your code please instead of posting an exception.

Comment: @TomJoney This is all I could find in crashlytics. It doesn't touch my code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an upstream bug on Android 12 + Samsung devices, Chromium team and Samsung are aware. Star this issue to follow along:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1271617

Until then, add platform-specific / vendor-specific disable of WebView usage or your app will crash out-of-process (in the WebView) and it can't be handled unfortunately.

Related https://github.com/react-native-device-info/react-native-device-info/issues/1351

Comment: If it worked for you - and I think it's canonical as Samsung actually responded :-), you should accept it as the answer :-)

Comment: For those following along - there is a great comment on the upstream issue showing this issue rising and falling with different devices now, not just Samsung. It *is* a Chromium bug though and there is still unfortunately no actionable thing a developer can do, as far as I know.