# App Crash issue in Samsung Galaxy S21 Series

Tags: android, react-native, chromium, crashlytics, samsung-mobile

I am working on React Native, and my App keep crashing on Samsung S21 with Android 12. Below is the stack trace that I get from Crashlytics. Any solution for this?

```
org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.isTablet 

Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x20c0025
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:240)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getInteger(Resources.java:1275)
       at org.chromium.ui.base.DeviceFormFactor.isTablet(:8)
       at cs.a(:4)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.e(:25)
       at org.chromium.content.browser.BrowserStartupControllerImpl.g(:26)
       at E8.run(:127)
       at org.chromium.base.ThreadUtils.f(:6)
       at EB0.g(:209)
       at EB0.b(:141)
       at EB0.f(:8)
       at com.android.webview.chromium.WebViewChromiumFactoryProvider.getStatics(:7)
       at android.webkit.WebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(WebView.java:2009)
       at com.cleadigital.clea.MainApplication.onCreate(MainApplication.java:59)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1211)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:7429)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:309)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2268)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
       at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8582)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:563)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1133)
```

Comment: Tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70185111/8196025)?

Comment: is it crash even with fresh project ?