# Java: toString vs. string concatentation?

Tags: java, string

Is there a reason to prefer either string concatenation or invoking `toString` when converting objects to string representations?

Does string concatenation cause the object's `toString` method to be invoked?

```
String s;
Properties p = System.getProperties();
s = p.toString();
s = "" + p;
```

Comment: Basically, concatenation involves an extra `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Slightly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/47605/string-concatenation-concat-vs-operator

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis, is that a reason to prefer one over the other?  It's not a duplicate question.

Comment: `p.toString()` doesn't involve a new object. `"" + p` involves a new object. (Though I would imagine the `""` could be removed by a smart compiler.) After that, it's all opinion, what looks better.

Comment: so your answer is "there's no reason to prefer one over the other"?

Comment: I would say that, yes.

Comment: great.  put that in an answer and unmark this as a duplicate!

Comment: Anything we put in an answer here will repeat what is already stated in the duplicate: _So...very similar things happens in both cases. One just does a little more work._

Comment: There's probably a better duplicate, fine.

Comment: lol, everything except the answer to the original question, which was "is one preferrable to the other".

Comment: I hope you can infer that for yourself given all the details :)

Comment: [This is more appropriate.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752347/string-valueof-vs-concatenation-with-empty-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

p.toString() is better.

When you say s=""+p, the compiler makes something like this:

```
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("").append(p.toString());
    s=sb.toString();
}
```

So, yes, ""+p does mean that p.toString() gets called, but it also adds a lot of extra work.

The best thing that can happen is that the compiler recognizes that it's the same as p.toString() and just calls that instead, but you shouldn't count on that.

Comment: I think it does `String.valueOf(p)`, not `p.toString()` though the former calls the latter when `p != null`.