# Java String intToStr = "" + 5; Why can't I do this?

Tags: java, string

I've had a few people tell me that things like this are super lazy:

```
int val = 5;
System.out.println("" + val);
String myStr = "" + val;
```

Why is this better than String.valueOf(val)?  Isn't it doing the exact same thing under the hood?

Comment: This has already been answered before, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752347/string-valueof-vs-concatenation-with-empty-string

Comment: It isn't better than `String.valueOf(int)`; it's worse and it's lazy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not really "better", just shorter, making it easier to read and type. There is (virtually) no ther difference, even though a real purist might, probably, say, this is actually worse, because (at least, in the absence of optimization), this creates an intermediate `StringBuilder` object, that is then appended a character before being converted into a String, so, this may be spending more ticks, than `.valueOf`.

Answer (score 0):

From [JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1):

> An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression.
>
> For primitive types, an implementation may also optimize away the creation of a wrapper object by converting directly from a primitive type to a string.