# unable to set Text in TextView using AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-asynctask

I have an `AsyncTask`, I want to set Text of `TextView` in my **layout.xml** file, but my Application is Crashed with Error this

> android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x2

kindly help me!

```
public class UploadVideo extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {     
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
        transferUtility = Util.getTransferUtility(this);     
        requestWindowFeature(getWindow().FEATURE_NO_TITLE);     
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_INDETERMINATE_PROGRESS);     
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,     
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);     
        setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);          
        context = this;          
        new get_people_data().execute();
    }


    public class get_people_data extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{          
        final String TAG = "get_people_data";          
        String API_URL = "http://api.expressionsapp.com/users/auth0_5732cc152781665b7b5dfee6/status/";     
        int front;     
        int behind;     
        @Override     
        protected String doInBackground(String...arg0)
        {     
            try     
            {     
                JsonParser jParser = new JsonParser();     
                JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(API_URL);     
                behind= json.getInt("countBack");     
                front= json.getInt("countFront");          
            }catch (JSONException e)
            {     
                e.printStackTrace();     
            }     
            return null;     
        }          
        @Override     
        protected void onPostExecute(String s)
        {     
            TextView ppl_infront;     
            TextView ppl_behind;     
            ppl_infront = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppl_infront);     
            ppl_infront.setText(front);     
            ppl_behind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppl_behind);     
            ppl_behind.setText(behind);     
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: At first declare `TextView` Global section

Comment: show your xml please

Comment: Intialize the textview in oncreate

Comment: You should initialize your widget in `onCreate()` and declare it globally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20177003/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x0)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is on

```
ppl_infront.setText(front);  
ppl_behind.setText(behind);
```

because you are passing and int(front is of type int) using

> **final void**    setText(int resid)

and the system search in the R file with that int id (that is a file generated automatically)

Change with this:

```
ppl_infront.setText(String.valueOf(front));       
ppl_behind.setText(String.vaueOf(behind));
```

using

> **final void**    setText(CharSequence text)

here the official [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html)

Comment: Bingo. You nailed it! Nice catch.

Answer (score 0):

Do your

`ppl_infront = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppl_infront);`

and

`ppl_behind = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ppl_behind);`

in `onCreate()` method below your `setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);`

If it does not solve your issue, post your xml file.

Comment: If he uses this, the textview will have to be instance variable. Why is this needed?

Comment: It is not about keeping it global. If he does it in `onPostExecute()` the context for `findViewById()` will be the async task context. Hence it may crash.

Comment: I doubt that man. Since, `findViewById` is being run in `Activity` context only. There is no `findViewById` in `AsyncTask` so it just cannot take its context.

Comment: If you can see his `onPostExecute()` method, it contains `findViewById()` for the textView.

Comment: I'm saying the `onPostExecute()` method in Android doesn't have a `findViewById()`. So, the code above is running in Activity context only which does have that method since it compiles and run properly.

Answer (score 0):

**quick solution :**

if you don't want to mess with `String.value(front)`, you can set your text as follow.

```
ppl_behind.setText(front + "");
```

Comment: quick solution but very bad programming suggestion! Please do not follow that bad practise

Comment: what is bad in that mate? if you can explain, may be it will help me.

Comment: Ok,the code work but is all question of legibility and clean code. The code MUST explain itself. concatenate an empty string is just a workaround.

Comment: well.. for me what works is worth. I believe that your code is inappropriate as log as it's affecting  your app performance. but i am glad you pointed out.

Comment: I do not think so, read this interesting [blog](https://dzone.com/articles/stringvalueofint-vs-int) and this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7752347/string-valueof-vs-concatenation-with-empty-string) ...you will change your mind!

Comment: it's matter of 0.014 microseconds. it's totally depends upon developer and how many time he gonna use this. anyways thanks for the article. it really helped. and just for the record you should edit your comment. link in broken i guess.